# How to migrate from GCP's managed ssl to a different service

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I have been hosting by web app on GCP App Engine using their's managed certificate feature for SSL. Now I would like to migrate to a different provider, but I don't want my users to be warned by browser that the certificate has changed. Is there a way to extract a managed certificate and use it somewhere else?

Comment: 1) Users are not warned when a web server changes SSL certificates unless the client application has that detection built-in. In that case, you cannot prevent detection of a new SSL certificate. 2) You cannot extract/download a Google Managed SSL certificate. Google protects the private key. 3) Why do you want to change SSL certificate issuers?  Do you mean you want to move your application to a different service or cloud? Understanding what you are trying to accomplish will help create a good answer.

Comment: 1) Do browsers have that detection built-in?
3) Yes, I want to move to a different service and I'm afraid that if I change the SSL certificate users may think that my page is not trustworthy

Comment: Browsers do not care if you change SSL certificates. Browsers will validate whatever certificate is presented. Changing certificates should not cause any problems for normal websites and web browsing. I am curious, why do you think there would be a problem? If your concerns were valid, billions of users would scream as certificates expire and are routinely replaced on every site in the world.

Comment: @JohnHanley :
I think I have seen such a warning in my browser on some site. I was thinking that browser will warn you only if the certificate changed before the expiration date.